# Inconsistency of `this` when debugging a typescript program under VS code

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

edit: I think I have seen this problem when using chrome to debug my full application.  So, not sure if this is a typescript issue or a VScode issue.

I was about to submit when I thought I should try it using chrome as the debugger instead of VS code. Chrome works as expected, but VS code shows the problem illustrated below.

I distilled the following down from a larger program that was giving me some strange behavior when examining things in the debugger.  The program appears to work correctly in terms of what it prints out, but if I run it in VS code or attach to a running process, when inspecting the value of `this` inside `somePrivateArrowFunc`, I see different results in the debugger than are printed out to the console:

```
class MyClass {
  someField: number = 123;

  private somePrivateArrowFunc = () => {
    console.log("somePrivateArrowFunc", this);
  };

  funcRefs = [this.somePrivateArrowFunc];

  funcRef = this.somePrivateArrowFunc;

  public somePublicRegularFunc() {
    console.log("somePublicRegularFunc", this); // debugger sees "this" as instance of MyClass
    for (let f of this.funcRefs) {
      f(); // debugger sees "this" as the global object inside somePrivateArrowFunc
    }
    this.funcRefs[0](); // debugger sees "this" as an array containing f inside somePrivateArrowFunc
    this.funcRef(); // debugger sees "this" as an instance of MyClass inside somePrivateArrowFunc
  }
}

var c:MyClass = new MyClass();

c.somePublicRegularFunc();
```

The output printed to the console indicates that the value of `this` is always an instance of `MyClass`, but a breakpoint on that same `console.log` line sees 3 different behaviors:

```
somePublicRegularFunc MyClass {
  someField: 123,
  somePrivateArrowFunc: [Function (anonymous)],
  funcRefs: [ [Function (anonymous)] ],
  funcRef: [Function (anonymous)]
}
somePrivateArrowFunc MyClass {
  someField: 123,
  somePrivateArrowFunc: [Function (anonymous)],
  funcRefs: [ [Function (anonymous)] ],
  funcRef: [Function (anonymous)]
}
somePrivateArrowFunc MyClass {
  someField: 123,
  somePrivateArrowFunc: [Function (anonymous)],
  funcRefs: [ [Function (anonymous)] ],
  funcRef: [Function (anonymous)]
}
somePrivateArrowFunc MyClass {
  someField: 123,
  somePrivateArrowFunc: [Function (anonymous)],
  funcRefs: [ [Function (anonymous)] ],
  funcRef: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

I got these results using Version 4.6.3 of `tsc` and node v16.13.0 (I also saw the same with earlier versions of both).

Comment: inside arrow function you should not use `this` because it is not clear from which context it is. always use `function` functions that have a defined `this` or you can set a particular `this` you want

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you see as `this` with the debugger is simply and really NOT the `this` that is actually used by your `somePrivateArrowFunc` [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

As expected by design, and as confirmed by your console output, `this` in the arrow function is easily predictable and always the same: it is the value **where the arrow function is expressed**. In your case, the arrow function is expressed during the [instance initialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#initialization-order), hence it is your instance.

But the `this` that you inspect in your debugger is rather the context, i.e. what a normal `function` would get as `this`. Which, therefore, depends on how you called the function:

- `f()`: no context, `this` is global
- `funcRefs[0]()`: context is `funcRefs`, i.e. the array
- `this.funcRef()`: context is the same as the call `c.somePublicRegularFunc()`, hence is `c`, i.e. an instance

If you turn your arrow function into a normal `function`, then your console output will reflect the `this` that you get in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a newer target language version (es2022 instead of es5 or es6) fixed the problem.  The debugger sees the correct value of this in all 3 scenarios.